# Why name is null in base class

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

```
open class Base( open val name : String){
    init {
        println("initializing base with name = $name")
    }
    open val size : Int = name.length.also {
        println("Initializing size in base with $it")
    }
}
class Derived constructor(override val name: String, val lastName : String) : Base(name){
    override val size : Int = (name.length + lastName.length).also {
        println("Initialzing derived size with $it")
    }
}
fun main(){
    val derived = Derived("Tarun", "Chawla")
    var base : Base = derived
    println(base.size)
}
```

When it is run it throws null exception and how kotlin fails to see it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Base.<init>(main.kt:5)
    at Derived.<init>(main.kt:9)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:15)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt)
```

First am not able to understand the reason why name is null in base class and how it bypassed kotlin.

Comment: You should never make "any field in the constructor open", removing `override val` from the derived solves the issue, and ps: remove the open from the constructor if you can.

Comment: the value in the base class is set first, and is overridden by the value of derived class, base has no longer access to its property, compiler will also show you `Accessing non-final property name in constructor` warning when you try to access name.

Comment: Animesh, can you please point me to some kotlin doc which states something like you said above?

Comment: and am not getting warning from intellij ide.

Comment: I don't think what you are saying is entirely correct, you can copy paste the code in intellij ide ce and check yourself. If I move the name from base class from primary constructor to inside base class then problem goes away but intellij gives me suggestion to move it to primary constructor :D

Comment: It's OK to have an open property in the constructor, but you should not access open properties or functions in the initializer. The IDE should be showing you a warning where you use `name` in the `init` block of `Base`.

Comment: Am seeing this warning "Accessing non-final property name in constructor", note sure what this means exactly. I feel this should have been more explicit, in this age when we have to work on 4 languages, these things are very difficult to debug.

Comment: `open` and `final` are opposites, so "non-final" means the same thing as `open`. A constructor (which the `init` block is part of) should not access anything that is `open` because it can have unpredictable behavior. This is also a problem in Java, but Java's compiler doesn't warn you about it for some reason.

Comment: The reason why it's bad to access overridable properties or functions from a constructor/initialiser is that it runs _before_ any subclass constructor/initialiser, so the subclass isn't initialised yet and is probably in an inconsistent state.  (Its properties may be 0/false/null even if normally non-nullable, and its class invariants probably won't hold.  That can easily cause errors or strange behaviour.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that base class object is in inconsistent state as you have overridden that in sub class which is not initialized yet.